# MySQL query multiple column ordering

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I've written a query which should grab 15 most recent results from the 'messages' table, but order results by date in descending direction. My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
    WHERE chatID = 1 
    ORDER BY ID DESC, timeSent ASC 
    LIMIT 15
```

As you can see, I am using the 'ID DESC' to get the 15 most recent results, but the 'timeSent ASC' isn't ordering the results in the order I wish.

How can I correct my query to achieve this?

Comment: If `ID` is unique then it wont orde by `timeSent`.

Comment: Do you want it by date ascending or descending? Not sure if there's a mistake in your post. (You ask by date descending but use `ASC` keyword in your query.)

Comment: try it ORDER BY timeSent ASC,ID DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First fetch the messages by ordering the `ID` then sort it according to `timeSent`. You can try this -

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE chatID = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 15) messages_ordered 
ORDER BY timeSent ASC
```